# Multiple clients with sockets not working, even if using while loop

Tags: java, sockets

I'm making some kind of sockets messaging system. And when connected, if it was 1 client, the socket works perfect. When another client connects, messages sent from it won't appear at the server. And messages sent from the server won't appear in it. But messages to and from client one appear..
I assume problem is from server, since 1 client works.. so heres the code:
My Server code:

```
    public void startRunning() {
    try {
        server = new ServerSocket(6781, 100);
        while (true) {
            try {
                waitForConnection();
                setupStreams();
                whileChatting();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                showMessage("\nConnection ended by server");
            } finally {
                closeStuff();
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void waitForConnection() throws IOException {
    showMessage("\nWaiting for a Client..");
    socket = server.accept();
    showMessage("\nConnected to: " + socket.getInetAddress().getHostName());

}

private void setupStreams() throws IOException {
    dout = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    dout.flush();
    din = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    showMessage("\nStreams are now Set up!");

}

private void whileChatting() throws IOException {
    String msg = "You are now connected to the server!";
    sendMessage(msg);
    ableToType(true);
    do {
        try {
            msg = (String) din.readObject();
            showMessage("\n" + msg);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            showMessage("\nIDK What happened, what the hell did the user send..");
        }
    } while (!msg.equals("CLIENT: END"));

}

private void closeStuff() {
    showMessage("\nClosing Connections..");
    ableToType(false);
    try {
        dout.close();
        din.close();
        socket.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void sendMessage(String text) {
    try {
        dout.writeObject("SERVER: " + text);
        dout.flush();
        showMessage("\n" + "SERVER: " + text);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        chatwindow.append("\nERROR: Message couldn't be sent..");
    }
}

private void showMessage(String msg) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            chatwindow.append(msg);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: The server uses a single thread which handles the first connection, preventing any other connection from occurring until that connection is closed. Consider setting up a Thread pool to handle incoming connections.

Comment: your `waitForConnection` method only runs once. Therefore, once it has accepted its first connection, it stops looking for incoming connection requests.

Comment: @MikaelF
the waitForConnection is in a while loop, I am lost..
should I make an action listener, that keeps doing this:
 while (true) {
            try {
                waitForConnection();
                setupStreams();
                whileChatting();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                showMessage("\nConnection ended by server");
            } finally {
                closeStuff();
            }
        }

Comment: @Liwaa there are multiple tutorials on the internet that show exactly this. Google is your friend for this. As a starter, take a look at this [1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hZgntu7889Q), [2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2cQJJwoSNLk). You're on the right way, but you will need to use threads, which is a whole subject in itself.

Answer (score 1):

1. The `accept()` loop must start a new thread per accepted socket that does all the I/O to that client.
2. The `setupStreams()` call should be done in the `run()` method of the started thread, not in the thread running the `accept()` loop. `new ObjectInputStream` reads a stream header and can block while doing so.

Answer (score -1):

Okay so I managed to do something that works, I think I hard coded it though :/
check this:

```
    private ArrayList<Client> clients = new ArrayList<Client>();
private ServerSocket server;

public void startRunning() {
    try {
        server = new ServerSocket(6781, 100);
        while (true) {
            try {

                Socket socket = server.accept();
                showMessage("INFO => Client with the address: " + socket.getInetAddress().getHostName()
                        + " Connected...");
                Client c = new Client(socket, clients.size()+1);
                Thread thr = new Thread(c);
                thr.start();
                clients.add(c);

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                showMessage("\nINFO +> Connection ended by server");

            }
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private class Client implements Runnable {
    private Socket s;
    private ObjectInputStream din;
    private ObjectOutputStream dout;
    private int id;
    public Client(Socket s, int id) {
        this.s = s;
        this.id = id;
        try {
            din = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            dout = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void closeStuff() throws Exception {
        din.close();
        dout.close();
        s.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                String msg = null;
                do {

                    msg = (String) din.readObject();
                    showMessage("CLIENT #" + id + ":" + msg);

                } while (!msg.equals("CLIENT #" + id + ": EXIT"));

            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            try {
                closeStuff();
            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            showMessage("CLIENT #" + id + ": Disconnected...");
            clients.remove(this);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: See #2 in my answer. This code is still liable to block in the accept loop. If you're not going to take any notice of what you're told here why are you posting? And you should construct the `ObjectOutoutStream` before the `ObjectInputStream`.